# How to get all sub arrays of an array of length 2 or more in efficient way?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sub-array

```
array =[1,2,3,4]
```

Resulting subarray should be...

```
[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Good luck, because I don't think you can. Not at least, when N = size of input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O(n)? Maybe if you had infinite memory with every possible subarray in the real/imaginary number system stored for efficient accessing, then sure, you can have any complexity algorithm you like.

...But realistically speaking, you're looking at something along the lines of O(n^3), regardless of how efficient you do it.

```
>>> [lst[i:j + 1] for i in range(len(lst)) for j in range(i + 1, len(lst))]
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4]]
```

The one liner hides the two loops and the slicing operation, all of which add layers of complexity. However, it is as **efficient** and as **fast** as the underlying algorithm allows it to be.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get your result in `O(N`) in any way.
As there are `2^N - 1 - N` sub arrays with size > 1, hence the total complexity would be `O(2^N)` as you have to get all the sub arrays.
For `O(2^N)` solution, you can search for well known problem of getting `power set of a set`.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try this [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) solution to get all contigous subarrays of length 2 or greater:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [array[start:end+1] for start, end in combinations(range(len(array)), 2)]
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4]]
```